# cannot trigger action in a component when testing

Tags: ember.js

In my test, I am instantiating a component manually and appending it to DOM. For some reason I don't seem to be able to trigger the action on that component using click action, but if I were to manually call 'send' on the action then it works. Here is a jsbin link to the test: http://jsbin.com/copum/1/

```
        //THIS DOESN'T WORK
        click('button.click-me');
        andThen(function(){
            expect(find('#click-status').length).to.be(1);              
        }); 

        /*
        //THIS WORKS THOUGH
        Ember.run(function(){
            documentCollection.send('clickMe');
        });
        andThen(function(){
            expect(find('#click-status').length).to.be(1);              
        });             
        */
```

It seems like ember is not able to find the DOM associated with the action for some reason. Any way I can make things work with click event??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the visit at the top of your test :)

this now passes and works as you'd expect

```
    it("should show the text when clicking the button - using click", function() {
        visit('/');
        click('button.click-me');
        andThen(function(){
            expect(find('#click-status').length).to.be(1);              
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Shoot that was it. Thanks @Toran for figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want to call `visit('/')`, you can manually create an `Ember.EventDispatcher`, just don't forget to destroy it when done.

```
it("should show the text when clicking the button - using click", function() {
    dispatcher = Ember.EventDispatcher.create();
    dispatcher.setup();
    click('button.click-me');
    andThen(function(){
        expect(find('#click-status').length).to.be(1);              
        Ember.run(function(){
            dispatcher.destroy();
        });
    });
});
```